# Spring Security SAML uses few OpenSAML 2

Tags: spring, saml, opensaml

Spring Security SAML uses few OpenSAML-2 libraries which is currently end of support. They propose to use OpenSAML 3. However, below maven snippet of Sprint boot gets even the openSAML. What is the alternative?

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>     <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [no alternative](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/140) in the current GA (generally available) release of Spring Security SAML extension. OpenSAML 3.x support is going into next release of Spring Security SAML. From spring-security-saml [README](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/140):

> This project is being rewritten. There is a base implementation in the
>   develop including milestone releases in the milestone repository.
>
> In the develop-3.0 branch we are creating a solution that builds on
>   top of the milestones and is better aligned with Spring Security. The
>   intent with this branch is to merge it with the Spring Security
>   project and release as part of Spring Security core.
>
> For that reason, we will not be publishing any official releases of
>   the 2.0.0 milestones, but will maintain it until all feature
>   functionality that exists in the milestones are part of Spring
>   Security.
>
> We continue to accept pull request for the 1.0.x branch, but are not
>   actively developing it.

The [milestone repo](https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/security/extensions/spring-security-saml2-core/) has spring-security-saml 2.0 builds with OpenSAML 3.x as a dependency.